# erlang/otp crypto build issue

Tags: ssl, erlang, erlang-otp

i am trying to build erlang/otp from source on an Ubuntu machine and also on MacBook.

my requirement is to build erlang/otp with ssl.

I followed these steps, in these order

1. build and install krb5-1.15.1 from source
2. build and install openssl-1.1.0e from source
3. cd
4. ./otp_build autoconf (autoconf version 2.69)
5. ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local
   i get the following message at the end. that is, there is no SSL specific error in configure step

   `*********************************************************************

   `**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************

   `*********************************************************************

   odbc           : ODBC library - link check failed

   `*********************************************************************

   `*********************************************************************
6. make

i am getting this error.

```
 MAKE   opt

 CC ../priv/obj/x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0/crypto.o

 crypto.c:458:14: error: field has incomplete type 'HMAC_CTX' (aka 'struct hmac_ctx_st')

    HMAC_CTX ctx;
             ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:102:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct hmac_ctx_st'

typedef struct hmac_ctx_st HMAC_CTX;
```

i am not able to fix this error.

please help!!

Comment: It seems that the problem is related more to openssl, than erlang. You have the latest version of openssl, which seems to have this issue with the defined struct. I would suggest you to change to a previous version and try again or file a bug on openssl (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues).

Comment: i installed version `openssl-1.0.2k` and it worked fine, thanks

Comment: That's perfect!